# Will the installation of fingerprint gui harm my Windows fingerprint driver?

Tags: drivers, login, hp

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I have recently installed Ubuntu by dual booting along side Windows 10. My laptop model is a HP ENVY 15-j100. It has built-in finger print scanner. I was trying to find the software for fingerprint scanner in Ubuntu and I found this:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu .

It said to type the following commands to get support for fingerprint-based authentication in Ubuntu as well as the related GUI:

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui

It had a warning that "*It ought to be noted that the related PolicyKit package for the fingerprint stack will remove the default one (“policykit-gnome” , etc. depending on your environment) thus if you do decide to remove the fingerprint PPA, you must reinstall this package manually, or risk a broken system."

Now I might just be paranoid, but I thought installing that software might harm my Windows fingerprint scanner drivers. So I wanted to know whether it will harm my computer? If yes, is there any other safe way to use the fingerprint scanner for my Ubuntu login also?

Comment: No, it won't affect your Windows drivers. The very worst it could do is  screw up your Ubuntu installation, but even that's unlikely

Comment: thanks for the response Nick Weinberg. I installed the fingerprint gui but it is showing no device found. should I download any fingerprint scanner drivers for it to work?

Comment: I'm not what the issue is or how to resolve it,  but drivers designed for Windows will be completely useless under Linux; don't even try to get them working. Feel free to do some research about how other people have gotten the fingerprint scanner working in linux, and if that doesn't help, create a new question here on askubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will for certain not harm your scanner itself or your computer, maximal your installation, but then `www.omgubuntu.co.uk` is a very popular site which is good maintained, and if there would be anything suspicious with the `ppa` itself people would have already put tons of comments on that below the article and the article wouldn't be there anymore.

So my verdict, it is safe to use, nowadays hardware can barely be damaged by software. This at least for this particular `ppa`, otherwise simple rule of thumb. If you have any doubt in the credibility and integrity of a `ppa` don't add it and don't install software from it.